# logrotate doesn't respect rotate parameter

Tags: centos, logrotate

I've been having some trouble with logrotate, it seemingly does not do what I'm telling it to do.

Environment:

- Centos 6.4
- logrotate 3.7.8

My /etc/logrotate.conf file has the following:

```
# rotate log files weekly
daily

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 30

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
# dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress
compresscmd /usr/bin/bzip2
uncompresscmd /usr/bin/bunzip2
compressext .bz2

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

And the logrotate file I'm having trouble with is this (for elasticsearch, located at /etc/logrotate.d/elasticsearch):

```
/var/log/elasticsearch/*.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    copytruncate
    postrotate
        rm -rf /var/log/elasticsearch/*.log.$(date +%Y)*
    size 1k
    rotate 7
    daily
}
```

First of all, it's not respecting my `rotate 7` configuration, when I run `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`, I get a line saying:

> rotating log /var/log/elasticsearch/gravity-es-prod02.log, log->rotateCount is 30

... and a bunch of statements saying it's rotating 30 different *.bz2 files.

Secondly, I keep ending up with a logfile that is named `gravity-es-prod02.log.2015-12-01` (and any previous dates since my last manual cleanup), despite not having dateext enabled. These also don't get cleaned up, so I added the postrotate line to manually clean it up, but apparently that doesn't work correctly either.

**EDIT**
The cron file that runs the logrotate script is pretty standard:

```
#> cat /etc/cron.daily/logrotate 
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: What is the full pathname to the file containing your elastic search logrotate definition? How did you create this file? (Did it come from Windows?)

Comment: updated, it didn't come from windows, it was created from a chef template file

Comment: What you've shown looks sound. I don't suppose one of the other files in `/etc/logrotate.d` have mistakenly got global settings in them? Specifically the `dateext` verb.

Comment: nope, nothing but the commented out one in logrotate.conf

Comment: "_Any  number  of  config files may be given on the command line._" Can you find the `cron` job that runs `logrotate` and check that it's not including additional `logrotate.conf` files other than the single one you're expecting. It's `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` on my Debian (Wheezy) system.

Comment: looks pretty standard, I'll include it in the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32433/discussion-between-brdaha-and-roaima).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an error in your provided script (missing endscript):

```
postrotate
    rm -rf /var/log/elasticsearch/*.log.$(date +%Y)*
endscript
```

I believe this part fails and somehow applies global settings for this log pattern.

Comment: Thank you! I actually just found this out myself, looking at the output of the last run cronjob. I missed it the first time when I was debugging